# How to keep track of login time in the database so that I can see active users from querying the table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flash-message

How to keep track of login time of a particular user in the database so that I can see active users by querying the table.

Comment: When user logs in you would have a code snippet to authenticate login credentials. If authorized user is logged in. Here you can store current date time in your user table for that user.

Comment: @Samir I have  a code snippet to authenticate the login credentials, but I want to calculate the total login  time.

Comment: Current time - time of login will give you total logged in time.